# Laravel findOrFail does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I use findOrFail in my code it doesn't work

I've tried the find method and it works as I expected

```
public function show(Question $question, Reply $reply) {
    return $question->replies->findOrFail($reply->id);
}

BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::firstOrFail does not exist. in file
```

Comment: Your function has findOrFail and your Error has firstOrFail. It's weird! Which one is it?

Comment: agree with @AhmadKarimi. Also looks like `$question->replies` results in an eloquent collection, so you can use this [find()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_find) to "Find a model in the collection by key." but there are not any `findOrFail()` or `firstOrFail()` collection's method

Comment: BTW, you have `Reply $reply` in the function params, so why not just `return $reply`?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I probably have tried both and copied the other one accidentally

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ 'cause I wanted to make sure that reply belongs to that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `replies` is a Question relationship, if you use `$question->replies`, it returns a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance, and the `findOrFail` method is not available, because this methods belongs to the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class.

If you want to use `findOrFail` to build your query, you must use it like this:

```php
public function show(Question $question, Reply $reply) {
    return $question->replies()->findOrFail($reply->id);
}
```

But, as mentioned in the comments by @porloscerrosΨ, you have `Reply $reply` as a parameter in your function. You can simply return $reply:

```php
public function show(Reply $reply) {
    return $reply;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've fixed though but thanks for you explanation I didn't want to return "reply" 'cause I wanted to make sure that reply belongs to that question 'cause my route looks like the following

`127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/question-slug/replies/26`